# strtol help why does it return a 0

Tags: c, struct, strtol

so i am confused as to why the inbuilt `strtol` is returning 0. From the manual it says it will **return  0** if no conversion is possible. Though too me it should convert properly. This is the function.

```
struct coin * addCoins(char *val){
    char *ptr =NULL;
    long int denomination = strtol(val, &ptr,10);
    long int count = strtol( &ptr,NULL, 10);
        printf("%d",count);
    struct coin *k;
    k = malloc(sizeof(struct coin));
    k->denom = denomination;
    k->count = count;
    return k;
}
```

This returns long integers for the denomination of the coin, and how many of the coin's there are which are then stored in a struct of type coin. Which has the following `typedef`.

```
/* Each coin in the coins array will have a denomination (20 cents, 
 * 50 cents, etc) and a count - how many of that coin do we have on hand
 */
struct coin
{
    enum denomination denom;
    unsigned count;
};
```

The format of the file being read in is as follows.
**The first column is the denomination, and the second is the count**.

```
1000,3
500,4
200,20
100,30
50,5
20,3
10,40
5,20
```

the delimiter being the comma. We where specifically told to use strtol, otherwise i would use `strtok_r`.

Comment: The first parameter to `strtol` is `const char *`. Since `ptr` is a `char *`, `&ptr` is a `char **`. That, obviously, can't be right.

Comment: Well if i do not &ptr the error i get is: passing argument 2 of ‘strtol’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]

Comment: Obviously he was referring to your second strtol.

Comment: by applying that to the second strtol it still produces the same garbage. 
1000,0
500,0
200,0
100,0
50,0
20,0
10,0
5,0

Comment: @JoshuaTheeuf One bug at a time. (Hint: What do you think happens to the comma between the two numbers?)

Comment: The comma is the issue, it is not being converted, thus being returned as a 0. As per the manual.

Comment: @JoshuaTheeuf How about using strchr(ptr, ',') to decide the value of your ptr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code

```
long int denomination = strtol(val, &ptr,10);
long int count = strtol( &ptr,NULL, 10);
```

The second line has some problems.

The first argument `&ptr` should simply be `ptr`. That's because `strtol` wants a simple pointer-to-char as its first argument. So although the ampersand was correct in the first call to `strtol`, it is not correct in the second call.

Problem number two is that the `endptr` returned from `strtol` points to the first character that's not part of the first number. In other words, it points to the comma. It's up to you to advance the pointer past the comma.

Which then introduces another problem.  Before advancing the pointer past the comma, you have to make sure that it actually does point to a comma. If it doesn't, then something's amiss, and you have to fail gracefully. Since your function returns a pointer, you should return `NULL` to indicate that an error occurred.

Hence, your function should be

```
struct coin * addCoins(char *val)
{
    char *ptr;
    long int denomination = strtol( val, &ptr, 10 );
    if ( ptr == val || *ptr != ',' )   // verify that we found the comma
        return NULL;
    ptr++;                             // advance the pointer past the comma

    char *endptr;
    long int count = strtol( ptr, &endptr, 10 );
    if ( endptr == ptr || *endptr != '\0' )   // verify that the second conversion succeeded
        return NULL;

    struct coin *k;
    k = malloc(sizeof(struct coin));
    k->denom = denomination;
    k->count = count;
    return k;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution i came up with was the to tokenise the string before passing to strtol, but imagine there is a more elegant way to perform this operation.

```
char *ptr =NULL;
char *ptrs =NULL;
const char *deli = ",";
char *denominations = strtok_r(val, deli, &ptrs);
char *counts = strtok_r(NULL, deli, &ptrs);

long int denomination = strtol(denominations, &ptr,10);
long int count = strtol( counts,NULL, 10);
```

Comment: My slightly jaundiced attitude is 'those who reach for `strtok_r()` are usually reaching for the wrong tool'.  At least you're using `strtok_r()` and not just `strtok()`; plain `strtok()` is a much worse 'wrong tool'.  The code you how will work as long as you never pass a string literal, for example, to your `addCoins()` function — though you shouldn't be doing that anyway since string literals should be treated as constants.  Another trouble with `strtok_r()` is that it butchers the input string, and you cannot analyze which delimiter it found if you have more than one delimiter character.